# DirectorySearcher return empty result always

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have this code that run on PowerShell against AD and it works properly, it returns the user

```
$de = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry - 
ArgumentList "LDAP://DC=organizationname,DC=com", "username", "password", 
"Secure"
$ds = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher - 
ArgumentList $de, "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=myusername))", 
@("sAMAccountName", "mail", "displayName"), "Subtree"
$ds.FindAll()
```

But when I run same code on asp.net mvc using DirectorySearcher it returns empty result always.

What could be the issue ? How do I debug that ?

```
string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUsername"];
string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"];
string displayName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDisplayName"];

using (var de = new DirectoryEntry(adUsersContainer, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
    IList<User> items = new List<User>();
    string[] props = { "sAMAccountName", "mail", displayName };

    using (var ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=" + anr + "))", props, SearchScope.Subtree))
    {
        ds.PageSize = 1000;
        IEnumerable<SearchResult> results = SafeFindAll(ds);

        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            var user = new User
                    {
                        Username = GetPropertyValue(result.Properties, "sAMAccountName"),//;//[0].ToString(),
                        Email = GetPropertyValue(result.Properties, "mail"),
                        DisplayName = GetPropertyValue(result.Properties, displayName)
                    };

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Email))
            {
                items.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```

This is an intranet app, hosted and should work with Windows authentication, so basically logged in users to their machine should be able to hit website without login but :

1. they keep getting login prompt
2. and when we try to pull user from AD (we are able to get user from Identity - see below -) but still it returns empty results.

Code:

```
string identityName = User.Identity.Name;
int index = identityName.LastIndexOf('\\');
string username = index >= 0 ? identityName.Substring(index + 1) : identityName;
```

Thoughts ?

Comment: Can you confirm if you're missing `""` for displayName in the props array: `string[] props = { "sAMAccountName", "mail", displayName };`!

Comment: it is a variable not a hardcoded string

Comment: What is the value of `displayName` in the config file? Maybe, because of that value there is no result. In my opinion, either the value of displayName variable should be "displayName" itself, or there should be double-quotes in the props array: `string[] props = { "sAMAccountName", "mail", "displayName" };`.

Comment: You are saying if that any of these is not set in user record then it won’t return that usrr? i.e if i ask for mail and that user does not have mail field set then it wont return it?

Comment: Definitely DirectorySearcher would bring result, if there is any attribute value matching the set ANR. But, your queries doesn't make sense to me! Have you tried wrapping your code with try-catch, and see if there are any exceptions?